# Why root Can't open file for writing?

Tags: permissions, root

```
[root@localhost ~]# vim /usr/lib64/sas12/smtpd.conf    
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
log_level:3
```

:wq

An error occurs.

```
"/usr/lib64/sas12/smtpd.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing.
```

Why root can't open file for writing?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check that the */usr/lib64/sas12* directory already exists:

```
root@host:~# ls /usr/lib64/sas12
```

If it is not the case, you must create the directory before attempting to create the file:

```
root@host:~# mkdir -p /usr/lib64/sas12
root@host:~# vim /usr/lib64/sas12/smtpd.conf
```

You `vim` command should now work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually doing a vi for a file inside a folder that did not exist. As: `vi ~/bin/backup`.

Answer (score 2):

Either the filesystem is mounted read-only or this is not a `root` permission problem but a `vim` feature. Use a different editor or change the file permissions (e.g. make `root` the file owner), edit the file, and change them back.

Answer (score 2):

you can get this error when there is "+a" attribute set on a file.
the command `chattr` will allow, only, appending, but not deleting the existing file.

```
server123:/tmp # chattr +a manish
server123:/tmp # lsattr manish
-----a---------- manish
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thx

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if there is a swap file as well at the same location which might set a lock on the file for editing.

example please look for the file

`/usr/lib64/sas12/.smtpd.conf.swp`

If this file exists, then you can't edit the file. Try removing it and then editing it should work.